# How to keep :after pseudo element scrolling horizontally with parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

I am attempting to keep :after pseudo elements scrolling horizontally with a header that I have created, where the :after elements essentially act as background colors to content below the header. The content body and the header are both set up to scroll together. Unfortunately at the moment, I am finding that the columns I have created are not scrolling with the header and remain fixed on the page.

Based on the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892098/horizontal-li-elements-after-pseudo-element-transition), I am having trouble because the after element is positioned outside the normal flow of the document. Is there are a way that I can keep the :after scrolling with the header?

A small example of my current solution is provided below:

```js
      function rightHeaderScroll()
      {
         var rightHeader = document.getElementById('rightHead');
         var scrollPos = rightHeader.scrollLeft;
         
         var rightMain = document.getElementById('rightMain');
         rightMain.scrollLeft = scrollPos;
      }
      
      function leftMainScroll()
      {
         var leftMain = document.getElementById('leftMain');
         var scrollPos = leftMain.scrollTop;
         
         var rightMain = document.getElementById('rightMain');
         rightMain.scrollTop = scrollPos;
      }
      
      function rightMainScroll()
      {
         var rightMain = document.getElementById('rightMain');
         var leftScroll = rightMain.scrollLeft;
         var topScroll = rightMain.scrollTop;
         
         var rightHeader = document.getElementById('rightHead');
         var leftMain = document.getElementById('leftMain');
         leftMain.scrollTop = topScroll;
         rightHeader.scrollLeft = leftScroll;
      }
```

```css
      div {
         border: 1px solid black;
      }
   
      #screen {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
      }
      
      #header {
         display: flex;  
         width: 100%;
         height: 50px;
      }
      
      #main {
         display: flex;
         width: 100%;
         height: 500px;
      }
      
      #leftHead {
         flex: 2;
      }
      
      #rightHead {
         overflow-x: auto;
         flex: 3;
         display: flex;
      }
      
      #leftMain {
         overflow-y: auto;
         flex: 2;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
      }
      
      #rightMain {
         overflow-x: auto;
         overflow-y: auto;
         flex: 3;
      }
      
      .headerFiller {
         min-width: 200px;
      }
      
      .bodyFiller {
         min-height: 200px;
         display: flex;
      }
      
      .greyed {
         background-color: lightgray;
      }
      
      .greyed:after {
         height: 500px;
         content: '';
         position: absolute;
         width: 200px;
         z-index: -1;
         background-color: lightgray;
      }
```

```html
   <div id="screen">
      <div id="header">
         <div id="leftHead"></div>
         <div id="rightHead" onscroll="rightHeaderScroll()">
            <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            <div class="headerFiller greyed">Text</div>
            <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            <div class="headerFiller greyed">Text</div>
            <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            <div class="headerFiller greyed">Text</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="main">
         <div id="leftMain" onscroll="leftMainScroll()">
            <div class="bodyFiller">Text</div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">Text</div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">Text</div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">Text</div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">Text</div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">Text</div>
         </div>
         <div id="rightMain" onscroll="rightMainScroll()">
            <div class="bodyFiller">
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyFiller">
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
               <div class="headerFiller">Text</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I have already tried exploring the idea of simply highlighting the cells in the columns with the background color I want as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727029/adding-repeating-background-colour-column-to-same-div), but the performance at the scale I require becomes a major issue.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Because `.greyed`'s position is not relative, it's pseudo-class `::after` is absolute to the window element or any ancestor that is relatively positioned.

To fix this, add `position: relative` to the `.greyed` class

Comment: If I do that, I find that the grey columns can no longer be seen, it is as if it can't be seen over the top of the main content. I can see by setting the height that it is still present (due to the offset that I accidentally had in the example :P), but changing the z-index doesn't seem to display it or anything like that. Are there any additinal rules I need to add to make sure that they continue to appear in the main content (the height is set to 500px to deliberately overrun the bounds of the header)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue that I seemed to be facing was making position: relative on the parent, and finding that the grey bars would then disappear entirely from the content section. I believe this has something to do with the fact that they are in separate scrollable components.

It is far from an ideal solution, but the way I got around this issue was creating an item with a height of 0px in the top of the content and making the afters apply from there. It means I have doubled the amount of elements I need to achieve the solution, but it does what I require and doesn't seem to have any noticable performance hit.

I don't like this answer, and there is too much assumption as to why it is not working. If anyone has anything else they would like to add, I'd love to hear it. Otherwise this work around will hopefully help anyone else experiencing something similar.